# React native Unknown plugin error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a sample map project.It gives me unknown plugin error.

Below is the Code:

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'

export default class mapTestProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView>
         style = {styles.map}
         showsUserLocation = {false}
         followUserLocation = {false}
         zoomEnabled = {true}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
      height: 400,
      marginTop: 80
   },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('mapTestProject', () => mapTestProject);
```

Error Message here:
[image]
Please help me on fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have required module. It should automatically have resolved dependency, but something seems to be wrong. You can manually install the module

```
npm install module-resolver --save
```